# Adding Table Row by Javascript not working in <Form> Element

Tags: javascript, forms, element, tablerow

> Following script  add Table row successfully but when i add Form element top of the table and bottom it doesn't work.

```
<script>
        function addrow() {
        var counter = 1;
        $('#exampleTableTools').append('<tr><td style="min-width:150px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]"></td><td><select class="form-control" name="type[]"><option selected value="0">Text</option><option value="1">Image</option><option value="2">Image slide show</option><option value="3">Custom link</option><option value="4">Custom content</option><option value="5">Custom HTML</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr> ')
        counter = counter + 1;
    };

    function deleteRow(t) {
        var row = t.parentNode.parentNode;
        document.getElementById("exampleTableTools").deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
        //console.log(row);
    }
    </script>
```

> This script add Row in following table

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="exampleTableTools"
   data-page-size="10">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="col1" data-toggle="true">Title</th>
         <th class="col2">Type of content</th>
         <th>Operations</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>{here this javascript add td and tr}</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> but when i add  element top of the table and bottom it doesn't work. Kindly help

Comment: Can you show *where* you add `<form>`?

Comment: Adding a form should not change this behavior. Please show us a complete example.

Answer (score -1):

Why you using both JS and jQuery?
Please try following

```
<script>

function addrow()
{   var counter=1;
    $('#exampleTableTools').append('<tr><td style="min-width:150px;"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]"></td><td><select class="form-control" name="type[]"><option selected value="0">Text</option><option value="1">Image</option><option value="2">Image slide show</option><option value="3">Custom link</option><option value="4">Custom content</option><option value="5">Custom HTML</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default delete-row"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td></tr> ')
    counter=counter+1;
};

$('.delete-row').on('click', function(){$(this).parents('tr').remove();})
</script>
```